# What is this branching, brown-stemmed and fleshy-leafed plant?

Tags: identification, vines, fleshy-leaves

Please help me identify this one. I’ve got no idea where it comes from. Even the specialists at [FlowerChecker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.thran.flowerchecker) couldn’t help me.

All I know is that it’s quite robust (i.e. undemanding) and is able to quickly develop new branches.

[image: four pictures of the unidentified plant]

Comment: Someone has got to know what this guy is!!  But to my eye, TOO much water, not enough light!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a [Nematanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nematanthus) or "Goldfish Plant" of some sort, most likely N. gregarius which is the most common species.

Like most Gesneriads, they truly are robust and are easily propagated from stem cuttings or even fallen leaves.

[image]